# What's a good place to learn ASM online?

Tags: assembly, native-code

I want to learn ASM, and I've looked up quite some articles on the web, but I think great ASM articles are scarce on the web.

So, does anyone know where a good online tutorial is for learning ASM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, [Iczelion's tutorials](http://win32assembly.online.fr/tutorials.html) are the best.
Do read "The Art of Assembly Language" by Randall Hyde. It's a good book.

Visit the following link :

- [Good place to learn Assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523794/whats-a-good-place-to-start-learning-assembly)

Comment: After reading some parts of Iczelion's tutorials you've convinced me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's a torrent with an `Assembly Learning Package`. It contains software, books and a lot of useful stuff for you to get started.

Check here  : "[Assembly language Package](http://www.vtc.com/products/Assembly-Language-Programming-Tutorials.htm)"